# python pip install os windows errno 2

Tags: python, windows, setup.py, errno

trying to pip install the os modules on a Python 3.6 build on windows 10.  Searching has led me to run as administrator, to try to update pip, run with a different cache directory so it downloads a fresh tarball,  and also update setuptools.  No luck with anything.  Very odd to me is the double backslash in the filename.  I'm very green when it comes to the python architecture.  One thing that may or may not be relevant is that this is a replacement PC where I attempted to migrate data from my Win7 PC.  But that may be a red herring.  Anyway here's the output.  Any help appreciated.  Thanks!

```
c:\Python36>pip install os
Collecting os
  Using cached os-0.5.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\python36\lib\tokenize.py", line 452, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\swideb\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-_g65v8sr\\os\\setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\swideb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-_g65v8sr\os\

c:\Python36>
```

Comment: The double backslash is due to the fact that the string representation of a single backslash is escaped with another backslash ... hence the double backslash.

Answer (score 2):

The `os` package comes standard. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/index.html) for the Python 3.6 library. No need to install it with pip. Just `import os`.

Comment: Although incidentally, as this question led me to discover, there *is* a package on PyPI called just "os". I think maybe PyPI should block packages with the same name as standard library modules, especially ones so common as `os`. I will email the Python packaging mailing list to raise this issue...

Comment: The PyPI "os" package has "os-0.5/setup.py" in the "os-0.5.tar.gz" archive, which raises `RuntimeError("Package 'os' must not be downloaded from pypi")`. However, pip is looking for setup.py in the archive's empty "os" directory instead.

Comment: Yikes, that sounds troublesome. I agree that top-level modules with overlapping names should be blocked. For submodules, I think it's okay, e.g. `import mypackage.os`.

Comment: I think the intention was good here, to create a package that raises an exception when users try to `pip install os`, but it's misguided and poorly executed.

Comment: DOH!  Thanks everybody.  Now I guess I just have to figure out what changed that causes this not to work in Win10/Python 3.6 when it worked fine on WIn7/Python 3.5.  The error sure seemed to indicate it was missing something; I should have paid more attention.  Thanks!!

Comment: Did you make a file yourself called `os.py`?